# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Login failed for user in Console Application

Tags: c#, sql-server, console-application, connection-string

I've got a problem with a connection string. I was looking for solution, but haven't found good results. I'm trying do a simple console application (.NET Framework) in VS 2017. I've made a local database named `Database1.mdf` and create a table `Customers01`. I would like to show data in console.

```
// Step 1 Handshake with the database
SqlConnection myConnection= new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdf;IntegratedSecurity=True;User Instance=True");

myConnection.Open();

// Step 2 Specify the command request
SqlCommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customers01";
myCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

SqlDataReader myDataReader;

myDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

// Step 3 Use the data
while (myDataReader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(myDataReader[1] + " " + myDataReader[2]);
}

myConnection.Close();

Console.ReadLine();
```

It's a problem when I'm starting a run application:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-R0JM0JD\AQ'.'

My account is admin and probably this line of code must be the location of the problem:

```
SqlConnection myConnection= new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```

I tried to change `\\SQLEXPRESS` into `DESKTOP-R0JM0JD\\AQ` and change `Integrated Security=True` to `false` and added `Trusted_Connection=True;` but it still doesn't work. Please help.

Thanks for your answer

Comment: looks like you need to add the local computer user "AQ" to the list of valid logins for your instance of sql server express, for example using SQL Management Studio. Did you install SQL Server Express using a different account than the current one?

Comment: No, AQ its my only account in this computer and I used this same account when I installed SQL Server and Visual Studio. Maybe it's stupied question, but how can I add the local user for instance of sql server express?. Thanks for an answer!